# GPIO programming in C for raspberry PI

Tags: c++, python, c, raspberry-pi, gpio

I ve got a GPIO program in python .. Could anyone help me in getting the equivalent C or C++ program to run on raspberry PI ..

The python code is

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time  
# blinking function  
def blink(pin):  
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)  
    time.sleep(1)  
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)  
    time.sleep(1)  
    return  
# to use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  
# set up GPIO output channel  
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)  
# blink GPIO17 50 times  
for i in range(0,50):  
        blink(11)  
GPIO.cleanup()
```

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <header.h> // which contatining some delay function
void blink(int pin)
{ 
    //Program the pin (which GPIO) to  high
    //delay function
    //Program the pin (which GPIO) to low
    //delay
    return 0;
}
main()
{
// to use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  //check this fun def and find out what it is doing and code it accordingly

// set up GPIO 11 as output channel  

// blink GPIO11 50 times  
for(i=0;i<50;i++)  
        blink(11);

GPIO.cleanup() ////check this fun def and find out what it is doing and code it
```